# Ambiguous call to varargs methods

Tags: java, overloading

```
public static void foo(int... a){}

public static void foo(long b, Integer... a){}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo(1, 2); //Why is this call ambiguous?
}
```

I've read the third rule which is about variable arity invocation in this section: [Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), but I'm still confused because for call foo(1, 2), formal params long and Integer are both less specific than int, but it still raises a compilation error.

I tried with both jdk1.8 and jdk10, within eclipse and the command prompt, all I get is the same result: Error: Reference to 'foo' is ambiguous.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? It works fine for me using Java 8

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Total noob myself, but I was in the impression that varargs need to be boxed because they end up in a list. So maybe int to long vs boxing an int can't be properly compared for which is a better match?

Comment: Also, `1` is an `int`; `1L` would be a `long`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb not a `List`, an array.

Comment: @kaya ah I see. So no boxing going on

Comment: @alexander.egger I use jdk1.8.0_172 and eclipse photon

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the JDK version you are using.

I have run your code on a JDK 8 and it worked fine, it executed the first method. That is because, on JDK 8, the compiler is casting the numbers 1 and 2 to a int.

If you want your second method to get executed, you need to cast the first argument to a long value. Something like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    foo(1l, 2);
}
```

Comment: I also use jdk1.8.0_172 but I still receive this compilation error. This is too strange...